# Run windows applications in ibm bluemix

Tags: delphi, containers, ibm-cloud, firebird

My company has a local solution where there was a database server and application server running on dedicated windows server machine(delphi application server, firebirdsql database). Now a client wants to move its servers to cloud. Is it possible to move both database and application server into ibm bluemix as is without changing code. It runs on windows 64 bit OS. What are the options? Is it not recommended to run windows applications in bluemix? 
Can it be done with ibm containers - is it possible to run windows in containers?

Comment: Seems pretty unlikely given that bluemix appears to be Linux based and even that is actually an implementation detail. What do you know about bluemix?

Comment: see https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/202273/upload-windows-server-vm-on-bluemix-virtual-machin.html

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - thing is my company already has a bluemix subscription that it uses for different application which is linux based and use open source technology. We know some things about runtimes, services and running container images. We are wondering if we can reuse this subscription for this new requirement.

Comment: I wasn't aware that you could upload entire VMs, but that would seem to be your only option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take a look at the Virtual Server (Virtual Machines) on Bluemix and use a custom image running Windows. As reported on [Bluemix Virtual Servers docs](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/virtualmachines/vm_index.html#vm_index):

> A virtual server image is a file that includes a virtual disk with an
>   operating system installed on it.
>
> You use a virtual server image to create a virtual server. You can use
>   an image that is provided by IBM, a customized virtual server image,
>   or a snapshot that you took of another virtual server.
>
> Important: In Bluemix, you can upload virtual server images that are
>   supported by OpenStack and have qcow2 format only.

For more information, see [Virtual server images](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/virtualmachines/vm_index.html#vm_default_images).

Comment: So, if I have an ordinary Windows image running on VMWorkstation on my machine, that's not OpenStack type/support? you think you can enlighten me on this?

Comment: Are they? I think images running on VMWorkstation and esx etc are not openstack..  i was searching based on answer and I ended up finding this https://cloudbase.it/windows-cloud-images/. Is that only possibility?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to select the VM option with Windows OS which your application runs. So no change is required.